# How to prevent and minimize whitening (albication) of the scar on face?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery

Normotrophic scar (about 1 cm long) was formed on my face (lower eyelid).

Typically, with time scars tend to turn white. That probably indicates that scar tissue formation is finished. Then this white scar stand out against a background of normal healthy skin.

How to contribute to the skin for minimizing whitening (albication) of the scar so that the scar looks as a normal skin around it as more as possible.

---

What can be done to minimize albication of the scar at the stage of scar tissue formation? Thanks.